# Replace multiple occurences of string except the first one

Tags: java, regex

I have a string in which I want every occurrence of `§a` except the first one to be removed and the same goes for `§b` and `§c`. For example:

`§ah§ae§al§al§bo §bw§bo§br§bl§bd` should become `§ahell§bo world`.

In my case those strings will always have either one or two characters between them, resulting in the following regex:

`(((?<=§a.)|(?<=§a..))§a)|(((?<=§b.)|(?<=§b..))§b)|(((?<=§c.)|(?<=§c..))§c)`

However, this doesn't look very good and it will only work if there are one or two characters between the strings. Is there any better way to achieve this? What about performance?

Comment: If you can afford a length restriction between the start of the string and the replaced match, you may use a constrained width lookbehind, `text.replaceAll("(?<=§(\\w).{0,1000})§\\1", "")`, and that is the best bet if you cannot use code tweaks.

Comment: Well, lookbehinds have a fixed length.

Comment: Not in Java, see https://ideone.com/Uqo7Yi

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be a pure regex `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` solution, you can use an `appendReplacement` loop, and a `Set` that keeps track of first instance of each matched substring.

Java 1.4+ solution:

```
String input = "§ah§ae§al§al§bo §bw§bo§br§cl§cd";

Set<String> first = new HashSet<>();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("§[abc]").matcher(input);
while (m.find())
    if (! first.add(m.group()))
        m.appendReplacement(buf, "");
String result = m.appendTail(buf).toString();

System.out.println(result);
```

Java 9+ solution:

```
Set<String> first = new HashSet<>();
String result = Pattern.compile("§[abc]").matcher(input)
        .replaceAll(mr -> first.add(mr.group()) ? "$0" : "");
```

*Output*

```
§ahell§bo wor§cld
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty easy with String.indexOf("§a") and then just String.replace("§a","") on everything that comes after that character.

Might take up some more memory but I guess that you don't really need a memory efficient solution?

In any case, this will work anyways so if nothing else works, do this (even though doing it with 3 Strings makes it a bit more cluttered).

To get the String without the first occurrence just use String.substring() and indexOf()

Comment: Well, I'd like to use regex instead of a Java function/loop.

Comment: Alright, not an expert there but yeah if nothing else works you can probably fall back to this